# PropertySheet ListView behaves differently on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-shell, sharpshell

I have created a PropertySheet using SharpShell.
The PropertySheet uses a ListView with its view set to Details and Groups enabled to display some information.

The PropertySheet works exactly as expected in Windows 7, however I have now moved to Windows 10 (x64) and although the PropertySheet can be seen and the information it contains is correct the ListView is misbehaving. It does not show the Groups at all, the headers use the default 'block' style not the 'Aero' style as usual, and most telling of an issue is that the page is not redrawn i.e. I must click on the entries for them to be drawn.

I have tested the ListView in a simple winforms app with exactly the same settings and it behaves correctly.

I have used Spy++ to compare the existing (part of Windows) Details PropertyPage (Which also uses the ListView in the same configuratihon as I would like). I found some slight differences in which flags were set:

```
Windows Details PropertyPage        My PropertyPage
Windows Styles:     5201891D        Windows Styles:     56018141

WS_CHILDWINDOW      40000000L       WS_CHILDWINDOW      40000000L
WS_VISIBLE          10000000L       WS_VISIBLE          10000000L
-                                   WS_CLIPSIBLINGS     04000000L
WS_CLIPCHILDREN     02000000L       WS_CLIPCHILDREN     02000000L
WS_TABSTOP          00010000L       -
-                                   WS_MAXIMIZEBOX      00010000L

                                    00008141 (All LVS setting were grouped
                                    for my control but I worked out the 
                                    following)

LVS_REPORT          0001            LVS_REPORT          0001
LVS_SINGLESEL       0004            -
LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS   0008            -
LVS_SORTASCENDING   0010            -
-                                   LVS_SHAREIMAGELISTS 0040
LVS_AUTOARRANGE     0100            LVS_AUTOARRANGE     0100
LVS_ALIGNLEFT       0800            -
LVS_NOSORTHEADER    8000            LVS_NOSORTHEADER    8000

Extended Styles:    00000204        Extended Styles:    00000200

WS_EX_LEFT           00000000L      WS_EX_LEFT           00000000L
WS_EX_LTRREADING     00000000L      WS_EX_LTRREADING     00000000L
WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR 00000000L      WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR 00000000L
WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE     00000200L      WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE     00000200L
WS_NOPARENTNOTIFY    00000004L      -
```

I have created a very simple PropertySheet to rule out any issues arising from the functionality of my original PropertySheet. Unfortunately I get the same result. See Below (After clicking to force a redraw, and the windows PropertySheet that it should resemble).

[image: What the test PropertySheet looks like after clicking to redraw]

[image]

I have been unable to find any mention online of this problem or a setting in windows 10 that could be causing this.

If anyone is able to help I would very much appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: It looks like your shell extension works without themes. You need to create activation context that allows extension to load ComCtl32.dll 6.0

Comment: Thank you Denis. I couldn't see the wood for the trees! you are absolutely correct. If you give this as an answer I will mark it accepted. For anyone else that finds this question the C++ way so solve this is indeed to load the correct ComCtl32.dll but if you are using managed code via SharpShell or other you can simply use Application.EnableVisualStyles